# Magento 2 moving top.search block before minicart

Tags: magento2, layout

I seem to being having an issue with moving referenceblocks.

I have created a child theme based off of Blank. In my default.xml file, I moved both minicart and top.search blocks into header.panel like so

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" before="minicart" />
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" after="top.search" />
```

but I can't get the minicart to be after the top.search. Can someone help me? Below is a screenshot of how it looks once I moved it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move search bar and mini-cart into header panel try following

go to or create app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

add below line just after body tag

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel"/>
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel"/>
```

run this command

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

if you created a new custom theme run this command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

min-cart will be there but if you have default theme then header panel and mini-cart color will be the same find just before search bar.

Comment: I updated my post to mention that this is a child theme from Blank. I already have the code in there as shown in the original post but it's not displaying in the order I need it to. With the shopping cart to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom theme then it might be possible it is already override your XML before or it also possible it override in your custom module so reason for these your changes are not reflect.

So for that you need to check it is override or not please go to `App` directory and search in whole code `top.search` and `minicart` if you found it is override then you need to add below code there.

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" />
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" />
```

After that run below command

> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I updated my post to mention that this is a child theme from Blank. I already have the code in there as shown in the original post but it's not displaying in the order I need it to. With the shopping cart to the right.

Comment: Is there any code like this `<referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="true"/>` ?

Comment: Or can you update your post whole `XML` code so i can go through it.

Comment: You know what's so wierd? I was working on my local but it wasn't displaying how I wanted it to but when I uploaded the theme on my development server, it was displaying right.